# How to create global constant or variable whose value dont get reset after closing the app in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an application in which i add cars data and with that car data i also want to add a serial number for that car. Is there anything that allow me to add a thing globally a variable, constant or any function which increment and whose value changed by 1 on every car that is add and after closing the web application that variable's current value don't get reset.

Comment: You can use local storage or cookies

Comment: If you want to maintain the value on client side and persist it even after closing the app the you consider using browser localStorage

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh browser local storage? will the value remain same if the application is opened from another browser in different country?

Comment: You need to have a database

Comment: no It will only work on your machine. As @hellogoodnight said you will need database

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh i agree with you. you can post the answer for both possibilities db and local storage